# Meaning of this.$element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I recently started studying/working on jQuery, tryin to fix some visualisation errors on the website i'm working on, and while checking some code i found this:

```
this.$element = $(element);
```

As far as i understand, `$(element)` creates a jQuery object to work with, but i cannot understand how the `this.$element works`, and what it relates to.
The code comes from the tooltip prototype init function in bootstrap.js:

```
    Tooltip.prototype.init = function (type, element, options) {
    this.enabled  = true;
    this.type    = type;
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.options  = this.getOptions(options);

    var triggers = this.options.trigger.split(' ');

    for (var i = triggers.length; i--;) {
      var trigger = triggers[i];

      if (trigger == 'click') {
        this.$element.on('click.' + this.type, this.options.selector, $.proxy(this.toggle, this));
      } else if (trigger != 'manual') {
        var eventIn  = trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseenter' : 'focusin';
        var eventOut = trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseleave' : 'focusout';

        this.$element.on(eventIn  + '.' + this.type, this.options.selector, $.proxy(this.enter, this));
        this.$element.on(eventOut + '.' + this.type, this.options.selector, $.proxy(this.leave, this));
      }
    }

    this.options.selector ?
      (this._options = $.extend({}, this.options, { trigger: 'manual', selector: '' })) :
      this.fixTitle();
   };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter `element` is the *DOM element to which the plugin has been attached*. This is supplied to the `init` method (along with the `type` and any `options`) when a new plugin instance is created.

`$(element)` converts it to a jQuery object for convenient later use. Note: The overhead for *jQuery wrapping* a DOM element is quite low, so you could just store `element`, but as it is storing the DOM element anyway, it might as well stored the jQuery version instead.

`this`, for a jQueryUI plugin, *is an object instance*, specific to the DOM element in question. For this example it is an instance of the `Tooltip` class. The class instance is typically saved on the DOM element as `data` (literally using the `data()` method and the plugin name as a key).

So basically it is saving a jQuery version of the current DOM element, on each instance of the plugin class, for convenient access to that jQuery object within each instance.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `this.$element` is simply used to save the jQuery object you get with `$(element)` as a property of the `Tooltip` object.

This way jQuery won't have to search the dom for the `element` every time you use it.

Think of it as a cache.

Comment: "a variable" is not a complete/correct description. You have missed a key point.

Answer (score 1):

`this.$element` is just the jquery object for the DOM element passed into the function

- the prefix `$` (on `this.$element`) is just good practice when initializing jquery variables
- `this` just binds that variable to the context it's in

Comment: This one is also incomplete. The caller defines the context of the function.

Answer (score 1):

`this.$element` is simply assigning to a property of `this`. The name of the property is `$element`. There's nothing special about the dollar sign in the property name, but some programmers like to use `$` as a prefix on variables or properties that contain jQuery objects rather than ordinary values.

This is in the initialization function of the `Tooltip` prototype, and it's used to save a reference to the jQuery object that the tooltip was attached to.